# List-inline in Yii2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

How to create list-inline in Yii2. Does Yii have a native method to create this using ActiveDataProvider?

Example using Bootstrap:

```
<ul class="list-inline">   
   <li>...</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my task, I used this example:

```
<?= Html::ul($items, ['class' => 'list-inline',
        'item' => function($item, $index) {
            return Html::tag('li', $item->title);
        }
    ])?>
```

See more: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html

Answer (score 1):

Of course `yii\bootstrap\Html::ul();` [Yii2 helper documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#ul()-detail)